# How do I get vim to wrap at 80 characters only for `gq` command?

Tags: vim

Consider the following example file, which contains a single line with exactly 80 characters.

```
==foo     ===  ============================================================= bar
```

If I select this in Vim and type `gq`, it will transform perform text wrapping because it uses 79 characters for the threshold.

```
==foo     ===  =============================================================
bar
```

This is undesirable. I'd prefer to have vim wrap text **only if it exceeds 80 characters**. I attempted to use the approach suggested [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/wrap-existing-text-at-80-characters-in-vim).

```
:set textwidth=80
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of Vim automatically adding a line break *as I'm typing*.

**How can I enforce the 80 character limit (instead of 79) *only* for the `gq` command, and *not* as I'm typing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove `t` from `'formatoptions'` and/or add `l` to disable wrap-on-insert.**

See [`'formatoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27) and [`|fo-table|`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table).  `'formatoptions'` is a string of characters that control how `'textwidth'` and `gq` work.  The letter `t` has this meaning:

> Auto-wrap text using textwidth

The letter `l` (lowercase L) is defined as:

> Long lines are not broken in insert mode: When a line was longer than 'textwidth' when the insert command started, Vim does not automatically format it.

I believe removing `t` should be sufficient, but if not, you can add `l` as well.  `l` is particularly useful for people who want `t` enabled for most lines, but also want the editor to "stop messing with my one intentionally long line."